# "Like never before" or "Like you have never done before"

Tags: phrases, context

I am a not a native English speaker. But the term "Manage Teams like never before" which our company thinks about using for advertising our software sounds strange to me.

Wouldn't it be better to use "Manage Teams like you have never done before" (by using our software)?

Comment: Commercial slogans tend to favor brevity over linguistic accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrases mean different things:
"Manage Teams like never before" -> [You will be able to] manage like **nobody has** ever done before.

"Manage Teams like you have never done before" -> this personalises the statement [You will be able to] manage like **you personally have** ever done before.

You should make your own mind up about which one will give the best profits...

Comment: Thank you! This seems very plausible to me now if I think about it this way.